# How to SELECT data from 5 different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, select

I am trying to select data from multiple tables. The main table is `Notices`.

```
Table: Notices

   +-------+-------------+----------------+
|  id   | notice_code | company_number |
+-------+-------------+----------------+
| 96008 |        2410 |       09844265 |
| 96014 |        2450 |       02640968 |
| 96032 |        2443 |       03666759 |
+-------+-------------+----------------+
```

I have to select related information for the rows for `Table Notice` from different tables.  Below are the other 4 tables and their relation with `table Notices`

`Table Companies` has a direct relation with `Table Notices`

```
Table: Companies

Companies.Company_number = Notices. Company_ Number
+----------------+--------------+-------+
| company_number | company_name | sic1  |
+----------------+--------------+-------+
|       02640968 | XYZ Logistic | 28220 |
|       03666759 | OPQ Logistic | 41100 |
|       09844265 | ABC Logistic | 49410 |
+----------------+--------------+-------+
```

`Table Sic_codes` doesn’t have a direct relation with `Table Notices`. But it has with `Table Companies`.

```
Table: Sic_Codes. 

Companies.Sic1 = Sic_code.Code
+-------+----------------+
| code  |  sector        |
+-------+----------------+
| 28220 | Manufacture    |
| 41100 | Construction   |
| 49410 | Transportation |
+-------+----------------+
```

`Table Insovency_Practionar` does not have a direct relation with `Table Notices`. There is another `Table Notice_insolvency_practitionar_ID` to create a relation between these two tables `Table Insovency_Practionar and Table Notices`

```
 
Table: Notice_insolvency_practitionar_ID .   

Notice_insolvency_practitionar_ID. Notice_ID = Notices. ID 
+-----------+----------------------------+
| notice_id | insolvency_practitioner_id |
+-----------+----------------------------+
|     96008 |                       1048 |
|     96008 |                        725 |
|     96032 |                        548 |
+-----------+----------------------------+


Table:  Insovency_Practionar . 

Insovency_Practionar.ID = Notice_insolvency_practitionar_ID. Insolvency_Practiotionar_ID
+------+---------+
|  id  |  name   |
+------+---------+
|  548 | Charlie |
|  725 | Bill    |
| 1048 | Andrew  |
+------+---------+
```

My expected output is the following: where company name will be coming from `table company`; sic1 and sector will come from `table sic_code` and practitioner will come from `table Insovency_Practionar`

```
+----------------+--------------+-------+----------------+--------------+
| company_number | company_name | sic1  |    sector      | practitioner |
+----------------+--------------+-------+----------------+--------------+
|        9844265 | ABC Logistic | 49410 | Transportation | Andrew       |
|        2640968 | XYZ Logistic | 28220 | Manufacture    | Bill         |
|        3666759 | OPQ Logistic | 41100 | Construction   | Charlie      |
+----------------+--------------+-------+----------------+--------------+
```

I have used LEFT Join in my QUERY.

Here is my query

```
 SELECT n.company_number
 , c.company_name
 , c.sic1
 , s.sector
 ,i.name practitioner
 FROM notices n
 LEFT JOIN companies c
 ON c.company_number = n.company_number
 LEFT JOIN sic_codes s
 ON s.code = c.sic1 
 LEFT JOIN notice_insolvency_practitioners ni
 ON ni.notice_id = n.id 
 LEFT JOIN insolvency_practitioners i
 ON i.id = ni.insolvency_practitioner_id 
 where n.notice_code =2410
```

Here is my SQL Fiddle.   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4887e2/2

I wanted to know if my query was right. Or is there any other better way to write the query. As initially, the query gave me wrong result when I was testing.

Update: I have figured out there was a duplicate entry. And that was the reason for not getting the expected output. I have now corrected that. But still want to know if my query is right or is there a better way to write the query

Comment: This looks like a very detailed question. However, it might help readers comprehend it if you could add a description, in plain English, what is different between your actual results and your expected results. There are more rows (four instead of three) and more columns, but perhaps you could narrow down the main thing you want to focus on.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your result.

Comment: Please put the [mre] in your post, not just at a link. (Then these input tables are redundant.) In a MRE give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why. Ie the 1st bad join. Don't just give wrong code & ask us to debug. Also this doesn't describe what the query is to return as function of input, what the example is an example of. How do we help get it correct? (Rhetorical.) Again, part of a MRE.

Comment: How is that you have same notice (96008) assigned to 2 different practitioners?

Comment: Oh Thank you.... @Viney. That is the reason for getting wrong result

Comment: Please act on all of my comment. PS That includes, cut the unnecessary columns out of your example, make sure it runs, then put it all here--exactly the same code. Non-code formatted versions are unneeded. (It's good that your table initializations are formatted as tables.) Don't make us go to the fiddle. But there are many other things my comment says to do. PS I guess you are giving the select & its output to say something about your desired overall output, but they are a misleading & unclear way to accomplish that because they aren't a subexpression & value from the actual code you run.

Comment: @philipxy : I have cut all the unnecessary columns I can think of.  I have also edited the question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what the problem was.  Thanks to @Viney

```
<pre>

+-----------+----------------------------+
| notice_id | insolvency_practitioner_id |
+-----------+----------------------------+
|     96008 |                       1048 |
|     96008 |                        725 |
|     96032 |                        548 |
+-----------+----------------------------+

</pre>
```

duplicate entry for notice id 96008. It should be like

```
<pre>
+-----------+----------------------------+
| notice_id | insolvency_practitioner_id |
+-----------+----------------------------+
|     96008 |                       1048 |
|     96014 |                        725 |
|     96032 |                        548 |
+-----------+----------------------------+

</pre>
```

I have also edited My question and have reduced the extra columns to make it readable for users